# Is AddAndCustomizePages only available at site level?

Tags: permissions, security

I've read this [forum entry](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/zh/sharepoint2010setup/thread/6be7430c-ca6c-4535-b389-332d048c43dc) which states that it is not possible to have AddAndCustomizePages work at lower than I site level.  I have .aspx pages in a folder and I would like my SharePoint group to only be able to edit a few of them.  Is there any work around to do this or am I stuck having to give the group permission to edit all pages on the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are referring to the "Add or Customize Pages" is a permission at the Site Collection level, and yes, is only available at that level. For what I know, for the mentioned issue going with Permissions is the only way (not recomanded though everytime).

Have you considered using sub-site with Unique Permissions to avoid breaking permission inheritance? Long term might prove better for management!

C:\Marius

Comment: It looks like the sub-site method is the best way to go about this.  Thanks.